# Is it true that $\inf\{\|x+y\|:x\in X, y\in X\}\le\inf\{\|x\| : x\in X\}+\inf\{\|y\|:y\in X\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Considering $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ a normed space, is it true that $\inf\{\|x+y\|:x,y\in X\}\le\inf\{\|x\| : x\in X\}+\inf\{\|y\|:y\in X\}$?

I tried looking for a counterexample, but nothing. And intuitively it looks like it is true, but I can't seem to prove it. Any help?

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match the question in the body.

Comment: Thank you! Already changed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that
$$\inf\{\|x+y\|: x,y \in X\}\le 2\inf\{\|x\|: x \in X\}$$

Let $\epsilon >0$. Denote the infinum on the right by $m$ and choose $x \in X$ with $\|x\|-m < \epsilon$. Then
$$\inf\{\|x+y\|: x ,y \in X\}  \le \|x+x\| \le \|x\| + \|x\| = 2 \|x\| < 2(\epsilon + m).$$

Let $\epsilon \to 0$ to conclude that
$$\inf\{\|x+y\|: x,y \in X\} \le 2m$$
which is the desired inequality.

Comment: It's true. How didn't I see that? Thank you so much!

Comment: @GreekCorpse Glad to be able to help!